# Unable to convert character to numeric and introduction of coercion NAs in R

Tags: r

I have a field called Usage.hours in dataframe which was actually a factor type and then I converted it to character type and now I want to convert it to numeric type so that I can perform some aggregate functions on it but I am unable to do so. While trying to do its introducing NAs.

```
unisim_usage_hours_may_2020$Usage.Hours <- as.numeric(unisim_usage_hours_may_2020$Usage.Hours)
```

Warning message:

> NAs introduced by coercion

Some values for the fields are 00:00:00,11:34:20 etc.

I tried using hms package and although it did convert the field to time format(hh:mm:ss) but it introduced NAs as well because some fields are having values as 138:20:36,210:45:12 etc, so wherever it finds hours in 3 digits it is introducing NA there.

Comment: Hello :) I am not sure to understand your question. Dates and times are not of numeric type in R. You need to use `as.Date()` or `as.POSIXct()` to convert the factor or the character strings. Then you can perform calculations. Feel free to post a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: What you show (`11:34:20`) is not a number. It looks like it might be *time*, but it is not a "number" that can be converted with `as.numeric`. What do you expect `11:34:20` to convert into?

Comment: How do i convert it to hh:mi:ss only as couple of functions are adding date also which i dont want.

Comment: That is *still* not a number. What do you expect to do with `hh:mi:ss`?

Comment: (I should clarify: it is not a number *for base R functions*. My answer suggests the use of the `lubridate` package, which does have the concept of a "time" without a day/date. I've not dealt with it, so that's all I know there. For anything else, you will likely need to demonstrate what you will eventually be doing with this data.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a *guess* at what you ultimately need: fractional hours. I think you want `0` and around `11.57` for those two times shown. I'm going to infer that they aren't meant to be time-of-day, just "time spent" (in `hours:minutes:seconds`).

Two techniques for parsing this:

1. Here's a trick that relies on R's use of `1970-01-01` as "origin of unix epoch time".

   ```r
   as.POSIXct(paste("1970-01-01", unisim_usage_hours_may_2020$Usage.Hours), tz = "UTC")
   # [1] "1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC" "1970-01-01 11:34:20 UTC"
   as.numeric(as.POSIXct(paste("1970-01-01", unisim_usage_hours_may_2020$Usage.Hours), tz = "UTC"))
   # [1]     0 41660
   as.numeric(as.POSIXct(paste("1970-01-01", unisim_usage_hours_may_2020$Usage.Hours), tz = "UTC")) / 3600
   # [1]  0.00000 11.57222
   ```
2. Parse it *manually*, assuming that there aren't any surprised ...

   ```r
   strsplit(unisim_usage_hours_may_2020$Usage.Hours, ":")
   # [[1]]
   # [1] "00" "00" "00"
   # [[2]]
   # [1] "11" "34" "20"
   sapply(strsplit(unisim_usage_hours_may_2020$Usage.Hours, ":"), function(a) sum(as.numeric(a) / c(1, 60, 3600)))
   # [1]  0.00000 11.57222
   ```

Use whichever makes the most sense to you, since you're the one maintaining your code. (If performance matters to you, then the second is faster only with very small datasets; on my machine, the first can take half the time with only a few thousand rows of data. Granted, we're talking half-time measured in microseconds, so it's not cosmic, but if you have "large-ish" data then ... *shrug*.)

Another option (though I don't know what you're meaning to do with this):

3. Use the `lubridate` package to convert it into a `lubridate`-proprietary class:

   ```r
   lubridate::hms(unisim_usage_hours_may_2020$Usage.Hours)
   # [1] "0S"          "11H 34M 20S"
   ```

   Over to you with what to do with those ... I am not well-versed in its use.

---

Data:

```r
unisim_usage_hours_may_2020 <- data.frame(Usage.Hours = c("00:00:00", "11:34:20"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: i also have value like 138:24:42,230:36:12 etc as usage hours.so all the above functions and other things which i have tried don't help since %H format is only used for 2 digit hour format.

Comment: *"so all the above functions ... don't help"* ... **wrong**. (1) It's important to show relevant examples in your question, I think these (at least one of them) are perfectly relevant examples to demonstrate that you are not dealing with time-of-day. The first few comments (before your question was closed) should have triggered you to suggest better examples like what you just gave me. (2) My #2 above worked on these additional samples, returning `138.4117` and `230.6033`. What (in R terms) are you expecting? And I say again, how are you needing to use these values?